# Tornado On RPi not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

Hello im trying to use tornado websockets on my Raspberry PI and i get this error

```
 File "socket.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tornado.httpserver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 31, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/root/socket.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tornado.websocket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 28, in <module>
    import tornado.escape
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/escape.py", line 31, in <module>
    from urllib.parse import parse_qs as _parse_qs  # py3
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 850, in <module>
    class ftpwrapper:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 854, in ftpwrapper
    timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT'
```

the code im using is from the website as a example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call your file `socket.py`. It's confilicting with the python library module of the same name.

Make sure you delete `socket.pyc` too if there is one.